# Journalctl logs for a unit running under different user without sudo

Tags: linux, logs, privileges

Let's say I have two users. One is admin and has sudo privileges and one is a regular user. Regular user runs a process and admin want's to see the process logs without using sudo. How to achieve this? I also tried to add admin into adm and systemd-journal and while the the error message about not seeing other users and system logs disappeared, the logs still don't show.
Process writes into `/var/log/journal`
dir stat:
`Size: 4096         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory Device: 803h/2051d    Inode: 17039878    Links: 2 Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root) Access: 2022-11-03 21:45:05.578697401 +0100 Modify: 2022-10-17 22:40:23.353619074 +0200 Change: 2022-10-17 22:40:23.353619074 +0200  Birth: -`

Comment: Welcome to the site. Where does the "regular user's process" write its logs to? What does `stat` return on the log file and on the directory where the log file is written to?

Comment: writes into `/var/log/journal` 
dir stat:
`Size: 4096       Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 803h/2051d Inode: 17039878    Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-11-03 21:45:05.578697401 +0100
Modify: 2022-10-17 22:40:23.353619074 +0200
Change: 2022-10-17 22:40:23.353619074 +0200
 Birth: -`

Comment: Thank you. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/722508/edit) your post to include that information, so that contributors see all information "at a glance" (reading through comments is rather cumbersome, in particular because of the limited formatting capabilities).

Answer (score 0):

The [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/255/journalctl.html) states that...

> Members of the groups "systemd-journal", "adm", and "wheel" can read all journal files.

So as long as you are one in one of those groups or the root user, you will see all messages logged to the journal.
To see only logs from a specific user you may filter for entries which match a given criteria such as the user id:
`journalctl _UID=1000`.

There are also other interesting fields to match against such as `_GID=1000`, `_SYSTEMD_OWNER_UID=1000` (mostly the same as `_UID` but also includes some pam messages when opening a new session), `_SYSTEMD_UNIT=user@1000.service`, and `_SYSTEMD_SLICE=user-1000.slice`.

You can see more of these fields when enabling verbose output for journalctl `journalctl -o verbose`.